# how to center a text

Tags: html, css

I am not able to center a text using following code. What mistake am I making ? and is there any better alternative ?

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr ><td id="azone" colspan=3 style="border:1px solid black"><span style="border:1px solid black;background-color:green;margin:auto;" >Tense</span></td> </tr>
<tr > <td style="width:250px"></td> <td style="width:250px"></td> <td style="width:250px"> </td></tr>
<tr> <td></td> <td></td> <td> </td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried **text-align: center** (CSS)?

You can also use the <center> tags if you want. Though it is not recommended, as they are deprecated.

Comment: The [`center` element is deprecated in HTML4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html) and should not be used.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to use `margin: auto` to center your text, but this only works with block-level CSS elements, which `<span>` is not.  As a result, `margin: 0 auto` has no effect on your `display: inline` `<span>` tag.  What you want is `text-align: center` in this case.

Also, note that I've moved some of your styles to a `<style>` tag at the head of the document.  This is a much more organized way to control your CSS styles and will help you avoid future headaches when editing your code.

Change your current code to this and you should be fine:

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
tr td span {
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:green;
  text-align: center;
}     
</style>

<table>
<tr ><td id="azone" colspan=3 style="border:1px solid black" >Tense</span></td> </tr>
<tr > <td style="width:250px"></td> <td style="width:250px"></td> <td style="width:250px"> </td></tr>
```

Comment: Can you explain some more about block-level elements Brian? What other levels are there? Thanks

Comment: The block level attributes are determined by the `display` CSS property.  The most common are `display: inline` (which your `<span>` tag is inheriting by default), `display: block`, and `display: inline block`.  You can read more here http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/